# How to record Screen activity using Media Projection and Media Recorder inside a service

Tags: android, kotlin, mediarecorder, screen-recording, android-mediaprojection

I have a foreground service which contains a floating action button which appears on screen overlay over other applications, the service is started from fragment. Now what I want to do is to start media projection when the service is started, it will monitor screen activity and media recorder will record it into a mp4 file. The problem is that how can I get result from media Projection when I start the media projection and service from Fragment. is there any way to get results from Media Projection in Fragment?

if I do it main Activity like below it will work like this

```
 class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    // ...

    private lateinit var mediaRecorder: MediaRecorder
    private lateinit var mediaProjectionManager: MediaProjectionManager
    private lateinit var mediaProjection: MediaProjection // Need to handle the projection permission

    private fun setupMediaRecorder() {
        mediaRecorder = MediaRecorder()
        mediaProjectionManager =
            getSystemService(MEDIA_PROJECTION_SERVICE) as MediaProjectionManager

        // You need to handle the projection permission and assign the mediaProjection variable

        mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.SURFACE)
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)
        mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB)
        mediaRecorder.setOutputFile(getOutputFilePath()) // Define this function to get the file path

        val displayMetrics = resources.displayMetrics
        val screenDensity = displayMetrics.densityDpi
        val screenWidth = displayMetrics.widthPixels
        val screenHeight = displayMetrics.heightPixels

        mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(screenWidth, screenHeight)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoFrameRate(30)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncodingBitRate(1000000)
        mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.H264)

        try {
            mediaRecorder.prepare()
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    // ...

    // Start recording
    private fun startRecording() {
        val mediaProjectionIntent = mediaProjectionManager.createScreenCaptureIntent()
        startActivityForResult(mediaProjectionIntent, PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE)
    }

    // Implement onActivityResult() to handle the result of the media projection permission request

    // Stop recording
    private fun stopRecording() {
        mediaRecorder.stop()
        mediaRecorder.release()
        // Release the media projection
    }


override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    if (requestCode == PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        mediaProjection = mediaProjectionManager.getMediaProjection(resultCode, data!!)
        val virtualDisplay = mediaProjection.createVirtualDisplay(
            "Recording Display",
            screenWidth,
            screenHeight,
            screenDensity,
            DisplayManager.VIRTUAL_DISPLAY_FLAG_AUTO_MIRROR,
            mediaRecorder.surface,
            null,
            null
        )
        mediaRecorder.start()
    }
}
}
```

Comment: IMHO, the recording should be done by the service, not by an activity or a fragment.